# How to wait for the function finish (Threads in Thread)

Tags: java, multithreading

I think I'm a little lost in Threads because I don't understand why it's not working...

I have a program that has Server Clients and Nodes. 
The client sends grouped data (GroupedDataFrame) to the server asking for calculation of e.g. averages. The server distributes this task to its Nodes which calculate it and return their results to Server.

**My problem is that NODE returns an empty DataFrame** (without calculated results) when I use applyWithThreads (**if I use normal "apply" (without threads) it is working good**).

From what I realized, **the command to create NodeResult does not wait for the previous function to finish i.e. applywithThreads**, as a result, it sends empty DF (because if I set waiting for example 2 sec its working :/, or if I use this commented out loop, but I know it is bad practice)

**I would like to solve it somehow! How to wait for applythread to finish (will form returnToServer)?**

```
    class ListenFromServer extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Object obj = sInput.readObject();
                    if (obj instanceof String) {
                        display((String) obj);
                    } else if (obj instanceof NodeRequestGDF) {
                        display("I have received NodeRequest from client ID: " + ((NodeRequestGDF) obj).getClientID());


                        // DataFrame returnToServer = (((NodeRequestGDF) obj).groupedDF.apply(((NodeRequestGDF) obj).getFunction()));  
                        DataFrame returnToServer = (((NodeRequestGDF) obj).groupedDF.applywithThreads(((NodeRequestGDF) obj).getFunction()));
                        // while (returnToServer.size() != (((NodeRequestGDF) obj).getGroupedDF().getSize()));


                        NodeResultDF nodeResultDF = new NodeResultDF(returnToServer, ((NodeRequestGDF) obj).getClientID());
                        sendToServer(nodeResultDF);
                        display("I have returned result to Server to client ID: " + nodeResultDF.clientID);

                    } else {
                        display("I have received something i do not know what is this :(");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    display("Server has close the connection: " + e);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is code of applyWithThreads:

```
    public DataFrame applyWithThreads(Applyable fun) {
        DataFrame ret = new DataFrame();
        ArrayList<DataFrameThread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataFrame df : this.data) {
            DataFrameThread tmp = new DataFrameThread(df, fun, ret);
            threadList.add(tmp);
        }
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_Threads);
        for (DataFrameThread th : threadList) {
            threadPool.execute(th);
        }
        threadPool.shutdown();
        return ret;
    }
```

and code of DataFrameThread:

```
import GroupFunctions.Applyable;

public class DataFrameThread extends Thread {
    DataFrame ret;
    DataFrame DF;
    Applyable fun;

    public DataFrameThread(DataFrame df, Applyable fun, DataFrame ret) {
        this.DF = df;
        this.fun = fun;
        this.ret = ret;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        DataFrame d = null;
        try {
            d = fun.apply(DF);
        } catch (InconsistentTypeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (ret) {
            ret.addAnotherDF(d);
        }
    }
}

``
```

Comment: You seem to be using some framework but you haven't mentioned which framework it is. I can't find any results on google for NodeResultDF or NodeRequestGDF so it doesn't seem to be a widely known framework.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Because its my own structures :D NodeRequest contains GroupedDataFrame and client id and function e.g average , NodeResultDF contains one "result" dataframe and client id. They are very simple only to send data between node and server ;)

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem in function `applyWithThreads` which you wrote yourself. Please post that function too, and other code necessary to run your program.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt i've added the code of applyWithThreads ;) All code... It's thousands of code lines, so I don't know if it makes sense to paste here it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your code. I'll try to go over them.

The critical ones:

- Your `DataFrameThread` extends `Thread`, but if you use a thread-pool, as you do with ExecutorService, the threads are not created by you anymore. Instead of saying `extends Thread`, say `implements Runnable`.
- Calling `shutdown()` on an ExecutorService does not wait for it to stop. You could call `awaitTermination` after you call `shutdown`, but that's not how you are supposed to use an ExecutorService.
- One improvement is to use `submit` instead of `execute`. `submit` returns `Future<?>`, and you can call `get()` on a `Future`, which will block until its complete.
- Even better, instead of implementing `Runnable`, implement `Callable`. `Callable` is for tasks that return values. Instead of calling `ret.addAnotherDF` in your `Runnable`, you return your DataFrame from your callable. Then, `submit` will return a `Future<DataFrame>` and when you call `get` on it, it returns the DataFrame object when the thread is done.
- Note: only call `get` on the `Future` when you have submitted all your tasks to the `ExecutorService`, not after each task (if you do it after each task, you are no longer parallelizing the problem)

Important:

- don't create a new ExecutorService for each `applyWithThreads` call. The point of a thread-pool is to keep it around for as long as possible, as creating threads is an expensive operation. And that's why you shouldn't use `shutdown` and `awaitTermination` to find out when your task has completed; that's why you can do that with `Future` objects.

Comment: Could you rewrite this code how it should more or less look like? (If something wouldn't working in my program i'll try to match it to all my code :D ) with using Runnable interface